# How high can aerodynamic drag be during rocket landings?

Tags: rocket-science

Reading about Falcon 9 and Starship landing profiles, I found out that the maximum Gs the rocket can experience during landing is greater than 1g (peaked at 5g for a falcon 9 and around 3 g for starship). If the atmosphere is slowing down the rocket during landing, the maximum drag that is possible should not be greater than 1g (a falling object can never have a net downward force more than it's weight, and if it is falling, the maximum drag it experiences can not be more than it's weight else it'll start to rise up instead of falling down).

So how is it that falcon 9 and starship experience aerodynamic drag greater than 1g?

Comment: "a falling object can never have a net downward force more than it's weight," That is not correct. The drag force depends only on the shape of the rocket and its speed, not on its weight.

Answer (score 2):

The 1g maximum the astronauts feel would only be correct if the object were released to fall from a less than terminal velocity speed in a uniform density atmosphere. Deorbitting spacecraft enter thin atmosphere at thousands of kilometers per hour. As they go lower into the atmosphere the air gets denser and has more and more drag. This sheds their high speed rapidly creating multiple g forces.. Once it has SLOWED to terminal velocity it will be at 1g.

Comment: Got it, I was miscalculating the drag forces (mixing velocity with acceleration). Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> a falling object can never have a net downward force more than it's weight, and if it is falling, the maximum drag it experiences can not be more than it's weight else it'll start to rise up instead of falling down

You're mixing up velocity and acceleration. An upward drag force of more than 1g on a falling object doesn't mean it starts rising up; it means that the descent is *slowing down*. There's nothing impossible about this.

It *would* be weird if the upward force continued until the rocket was hovering over the earth and then launched it back into the sky, but drag can't do that because the drag force is proportional to velocity squared, so it decreases as the rocket slows down.